# Laravel websocket private channel with pusher broadcast/auth return 403 error

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, pusher, laravel-websockets

I tried to use laravel websocket with ionic; i used laravel-echo-ionic on my ionic project

in `BroadcastServiceProvider.php` i commented the `Broadcast::routes()`  and added it to `routes/api.php`

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

I used another model `Customers` for my auth:api and use laravel passport.

in my `channel.php`

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Customers.{id}', function ($customers, $id) {
    return Auth::id() ===  $id; // i tried $customers->id to
}, ['guards' => ['api']]);
```

and in my ionic service provider i have

```
this.echo = new Echo({
                broadcaster: 'pusher',
                key: 'key', // .env
                wsHost: 'localhost',
                wsPort: 6001,
                cluster: 'eu',
                forceTLS: false,
                disableStats: true,
                authEndpoint: 'http://localhost/api/broadcasting/auth',
                auth: {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + res.token
                    }
                }
            });

this.echo.private('App.Models.Customers.'+this.user_id).listen('.test', (data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
```

when using public channel it work well, but when using private channel, the `http://localhost/api/broadcasting/auth` request return error 403

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the proper way to do it with auth:api but i move my `Broadcast::channel` that used `auth:api` guard to my `routes/api.php`, so there i can access to my `broadcast/auth` within api middleware